# Ограниченная установка с исходящей почтой

Tags: email, ubuntu

Есть небольшой сервер, на котором работает простой сайт. Пользователи сайта могут при желании подписываться на почтовую рассылку. Что будет наилучшим решением для рассылки исходящей (входящей не будет) почты?

Answer (score 1):

sendmail (хуже, но стандартен), postfix (лучше)

Answer (score 1):

Если ресурсы сервера реально сильно ограничены и требуется только рассылка почты, стоит взглянуть на [sSMTP](http://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP) (Simple SMTP).

Answer (score 0):

Настройка собственного почтового сервера для исходящей почты подразумевает наличие достаточно большого объема знаний. Здесь и правильная настройка DNS, и работа с большим количеством черных списков. Также собственный сервер нельзя оставлять надолго без присмотра администратора. Вы действительно хотите тратить свое время на разбор, почему Иванову письма нормально ходят, а Петрову вчера ходили, а сегодня перестали?

Я бы порекомендовал вместо собственного сервера использовать отправку через публичные сервера, например mail.ru. Для этого нужен будет аккаунт, но его не обязательно указывать в качестве обратного адреса, достаточно пройти авторизацию SMTP. Там есть некоторые тонкости с таким режимом работы, но вся информация обычно есть в общем доступе. Я делал подобную схему для mail.ru и gmail.com.

Хотя можно и локальный почтовый сервер настроить на отправку через публичные сервера.